# How can I extract the coding of Dark Mode and Toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I recently found a template that have built in Dark Mode with Toggle.
I have installed that template in https://tasknquiz.blogspot.com
I want to know how can i get the coding of same Dark Mode along with Toggle, so i can install it to my other website and make that website Night Friendly.
Is it possible? https://tasknquiz.blogspot.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if you want go into the code and copy the functions, but an easy and fast solution is to make it.

You can try the demo below.

```js
$('.toggleDarkMode').click(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass("Darkmode")
})
```

```css
body.Darkmode{
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggleDarkMode">Moon</button>


Toogle dark mode on / off
```